# Unexpected tIVAR, expected keyword_end String.Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with the following code, appreciate its not the cleanest, but this about the fiftieth attempt at refactoring the code so it works.

```
 @userId = params[:id]
 @user = User.where("id=" + @userId).first()
 @expertProfilePhotoName = @user.profile_file_name
 @expertProfilePhotoSize = @user.profile_file_size
 @message = "%s\n%s" @expertProfilePhotoName, @expertProfilePhotoSize
```

I continuously get the error unexpected  tIVAR, expected keyword_end, and not sure why I get it. I've tried all sorts of alternatives, but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with:

```
@user = User.where('id = ?', @userId).first()
```

Where your `where` statements binds the value of `@userId`, not concatenates it.

Also if you want to find an user by its id attribute you could use `find`:

```
@user = User.find(@userId)
```

And supposing you want to interpolate `@expertProfilePhotoName` and `@expertProfilePhotoSize` then you could do:

```
@message = "#{@expertProfilePhotoName}\n#{@expertProfilePhotoSize}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Find!
The issues is with the last line. I don't really understand sprintf in Ruby on Rails, but I've figured it out with "#{@expertProfilePhotoName} #{@expertProfilePhotoSize}"

Answer (score 1):

Sebastian's answer is good and his point especially about your `where` method is very important from a security POV and should be followed.

But to directly address the source of the error you're receiving, it's in the last line. You have a string followed directly by an instance variable, so it's throwing the exception `syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting end-of-input` (`IVAR` == instance variable).

If you're trying to use `sprintf`, those two objects should be separated by a comma because they are method arguments, but you are also missing the `sprintf` method call itself. Everything will work if you change the last line to this

```
@message = sprintf "%s\n%s", @expertProfilePhotoName, @expertProfilePhotoSize
```

can also be written as

```
@message = format "%s\n%s", @expertProfilePhotoName, @expertProfilePhotoSize
```

Comment: Thanks, I was going off a bunch of other examples I had seen on other answers and hadn't found the complete syntax. I had tried with the commas, but I didn't know the name of the method call! I thought there was some strange Ruby magic happening behind the scenes

Comment: Good explanation, also the sprintf clarification.